# refresh button is not able to refresh UIView in monotouch iPad

Tags: ipad, xamarin.ios, refresh, uinavigationbar, monodevelop

i am new to `iPad` developer,

i have created two or three `iPad` application in objective c using `Xcode 4.`

but now i want to create `iPad` application using `Monodeveloper` tool in `C#` language...

in which, i want to insert Refresh button, on my NavigationBar,

here is my code snippet,

```
UIBarButtonItem button=new UIBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonSystemItem.Refresh);
NavigationItem.LeftBarButtonItem=button;
```

i am able to see refresh button on my NavigationBar, but when i click it, my view doesn't refreshes.

how to refresh view, any idea ?

***Thanx In Advance !!***

**Any Help Will be Appriciated.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are initializing a `UIBarButtonItem` without a handler. So tapping the button does nothing.

Try this:

```
    UIBarButtonItem button = 
    new UIBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonSystemItem.Refresh, 
                        (s, e) => Console.WriteLine("Refresh!"));
```

You can also assign it after initialization:

```
UIBarButtonITem button = new UIBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonSystemItem.Refresh);
button.Clicked += (s, e) => Console.WriteLine("Refresh!");
```

**EDIT:**

Inside the handler, you must implement your own "Refresh" code, depending on what it is you want to refresh. The `UIBarButtonSystemItem` enumeration merely defines the appearance of `UIBarButtonItem` buttons.